# How to transform Ubuntu 12.04 into mac

Tags: mac

can anyone help me how to make ubuntu look like mac ? i tried using the ubuntu tweak tool. It didn't do me that good...

Comment: Take a look at [Cairo-Dock](http://glx-dock.org/).

Comment: Try MacBuntu because it looks exactly like Mac. Try lots of tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah !! in my old days, i was mad about customization.. and it was fun, anyways

You should try this http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html

it includes :

**Mac OS X Lion Theme, Icons and cursors:**

**Apply MBuntu Splash**

**Indicator Synapse (Alternative to Spotlight)**

**Replace 'Ubuntu Desktop' text with 'Mac' on the Panel**

**Replace Overlay Scroll-bars with Normal and many more features.**

Comment: if u found my answer helful pls ... vote for it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands in a Terminal (`crtl + alt + t`):
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins ubuntu-tweak mac-os-lion-icons-v2 mac-os-lion-theme-v2 compizconfig-settings-manager gnome-tweak-tool`

`ubuntu-tweak`: Go to Miscellaneous and switch off Overlay Scrollbars.

Apple logo:
`wget -O apple-logo.zip http://drive.noobslab.com/data/themes/mac/apple-logo.zip`
`sudo unzip apple-logo.zip -d /usr/share/unity/5/` (Press `A` when it asks to replace files).

Mac cursors:
`wget -O mac-cursors.zip http://drive.noobslab.com/data/themes/mac/mac-cursors.zip`
`sudo unzip mac-cursors.zip -d /usr/share/icons/`
`rm mac-cursors.zip`
`cd /usr/share/icons/mac-cursors`
`sudo chmod +x install-mac-cursors.sh uninstall-mac-cursors.sh`
`sudo ./install-mac-cursors.sh`

Autohide Unity Launcher:
`compizconfig-settings-manager`:
Behaviour -> Hide Launcher -> Autohide

Change Theme:
`gnome-tweak-tool`:
Themes -> Change Window theme, Cursor theme, Icon theme and GTK+ theme to MAC-***.

[Source](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/mac-os-x-lion-theme-for-ubuntu.html)